# Error using FileChooser in Javafx on android

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafxports

I have a JavaFX application ported to android using gluon plugin for netbeans. The application runs okay but i get

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

when i click on a button to browse a file. Please help with any fix or alternatives.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to create my own file system since the filechooser is not supported on javafxport..

Comment: To be honest: There is no other way, since the way mobile apps work on a device and have access to storage differs greatly from a desktop environment. So in the end, there is no other way as to take care of it yourself. Maybe this is not very pretty, but depending on what you need, it should not be very difficult to achieve (except, if you want to have specific icons, previews, etc.)